# Same tests for different langages

Tags: api, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, integration-testing

I have a C# api. Now I also need a Java implementation of it. And to maintain both api then.

To ensure both implementations don't diverge with time, I'd like to share the same tests between them (not necessarily the unit tests, but at least the end-to-end tests).

So far, I can think of two different ways to do it:

- Put both implementations behind a rest api, and test through this
  api. The advantage is that I can have the exact same tests for both
  implementations. The drawback is that it’s a bit heavy to put in
  place.
- Use Behavior Driven Development tests (Cucumber for Java, SpecFlow for C#), and use the same feature files
  for the different implementations. The drawback is that I’ll have to
  provide an implementation of the steps for each language, so there’s
  the risk that the tests are actually different in subtle ways.

I would be grateful for any idea to handle it in a more satisfactory way.

Comment: Just curious - why two implementations? `.Net` is now open source and all infra related issues can be resolved via [containerization](https://www.docker.com/) . In the same time if those APIs will be used as-a-Service..the language doesn't matter...?

Comment: Those APIs won't be used as-a-service. It is rather some kind of parsing library, and clients use it in ram. The thing is that we now want to be able to do this kind of parsing from Java programs

Answer (score 1):

IMHO the [Facade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) for the both APIs is the better option. It'll allow you to reuse the same test suites above unit testing (Integration, System, E2E, UAT).

> The drawback is that it’s a bit heavy to put in place.

I doubt that having double BDD frameworks will be a less effort. Your language bindings will have to be different (e.g. `*.feature.cs` and `.feature.java` files). The unit test framework that you'll have to put in place (NUnit, MSTest, JUnit, TestNG etc.) will require a separate [CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) server handling.

In the same time having only one implementation for all your tests will be a lot more feasible. It's not mandatory to use the same language for tests as the [SUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_under_test)'s one. All the tests will be in sync for both the APIs requirements, regardless of the language.

Comment: 1+ for  using the facade  pattern